error when compiling redis in ansible/playbook/ubuntu
fatal: [server01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "cd /tmp/redis-6.2.5\nmake\nmake install\n",
    "delta": "0:00:00.090760",
    "end": "2024-04-05 12:29:20.080910",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "cd /tmp/redis-6.2.5\nmake\nmake install\n",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": "/bin/bash",
            "expand_argument_vars": true,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 2,
    "start": "2024-04-05 12:29:19.990150",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found\n    \u001b[34mCC\u001b[0m \u001b[33madlist.o\u001b[0m\n/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found\nmake[1]: *** [Makefile:368: adlist.o] Error 127\nmake: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2\n/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found\n    \u001b[34mCC\u001b[0m \u001b[33madlist.o\u001b[0m\n/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found\nmake[1]: *** [Makefile:368: adlist.o] Error 127\nmake: *** [Makefile:9: install] Error 2",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found",
        "    \u001b[34mCC\u001b[0m \u001b[33madlist.o\u001b[0m",
        "/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found",
        "make[1]: *** [Makefile:368: adlist.o] Error 127",
        "make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2",
        "/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found",
        "    \u001b[34mCC\u001b[0m \u001b[33madlist.o\u001b[0m",
        "/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found",
        "make[1]: *** [Makefile:368: adlist.o] Error 127",
        "make: *** [Makefile:9: install] Error 2"
    ],
    "stdout": "cd src && make all\nmake[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'\nmake[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'\ncd src && make install\nmake[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'\nmake[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "cd src && make all",
        "make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'",
        "make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'",
        "cd src && make install",
        "make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'",
        "make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-6.2.5/src'"
    ]
}

To compile and install redis.
